# Tenho um projeto em JavaEE JSF e Primefaces. Como renderizar uma imagem salva no s3 da AWS pelo contexto(chave) salvo no banco de dados?

Tags: primefaces, jpa, java-ee, jsf-2.2, amazon-aws

Classe que envia a imagem ########
public class AmazonS3FileUpload {

```
private static AmazonS3 s3;
private final static String S3WAWSURL = "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/%s/%s";
private final static String S3_BUCKETNAME = "pres-juscelino";
public static String novoNome;
public static S3Object object;

static {
    InputStream credentials = AmazonS3FileUpload.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties");
    PropertiesCredentials awsCredentials = null;
    if (awsCredentials == null)
        try {
            awsCredentials = new PropertiesCredentials(credentials);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);

}

public static String uploadFoto(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(event.getFile().getFileName(), "UTF-8");
    novoNome = renomearArquivo(fileName);
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKETNAME, novoNome, event.getFile().getInputstream(),
            getMetaData(event));
    s3.putObject(request.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3_BUCKETNAME, novoNome));
    return new URL(String.format(S3WAWSURL, S3_BUCKETNAME, novoNome)).toExternalForm();
}

private static ObjectMetadata getMetaData(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
    metaData.setContentLength(event.getFile().getSize());
    metaData.setContentType(event.getFile().getContentType());
    return metaData;
}

private static String renomearArquivo(String original) {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "___" + original;
}

public static void deletar(String nomeFoto) throws IOException {
    String fileName = nomeFoto;
    DeleteObjectRequest request = new DeleteObjectRequest(S3_BUCKETNAME, fileName);
    s3.deleteObject(request);
}


public String getUrl(String foto) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(foto)) {
        return "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/pres-juscelino/" + foto;
    }
    return null;

}

public byte[] recuperar(String nome) throws IOException{
    //System.out.println(object);
    InputStream is = s3.getObject(S3_BUCKETNAME, nome).getObjectContent();
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Não encontrada imagem " + nome);
    }

}
```

Componete da Pagina

```
<h:panelGroup id="fileUpload" >
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{lancamentoTributoBean.upload}"
            auto="true" label="Copia NFE" update="fotoPanelGroup" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    
    <h:panelGrid id="fotoPanelGroup">
        <p:graphicImage
            value="/pres-juscelino?nome=#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto}"
            rendered="#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto ne null}"
            width="200px" id="foto" />

        <p:commandButton value="Remover Foto"
            actionListener="#{lancamentoTributoBean.removerFoto}"
            rendered="#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto ne null}"
            process="@this" update="fotoPanelGroup" />
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<h:panelGroup id="fileUpload" rendered="false">
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{lancamentoTributoBean.upload}"
                auto="true" label="Copia NFE" update="fotoPanelGroup" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        
        <h:panelGrid id="fotoPanelGroup" rendered="false">
            <p:graphicImage
                value="#{lancamentoTributoBean.url}#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto}"
                rendered="#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto ne null}"
                width="200px" id="foto" />

            <p:commandButton value="Remover Foto"
                actionListener="#{lancamentoTributoBean.removerFoto}"
                rendered="#{lancamentoTributoBean.lancamento.foto ne null}"
                process="@this" update="fotoPanelGroup" />
        </h:panelGrid>
```

ficou assim